# HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30050ms

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-batch

I am using Oracle DB with spring-boot(2.6.2), upon running batch services, I am getting the following error:

*
36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
31mERROR 36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30050ms.
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.: HikariPool-2 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=1)
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.: HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=0)
33m WARN 36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
31mERROR 36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.: HikariPool-2 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=1)
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
32mDEBUG 36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=0)
33m WARN 36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null

*

I see sometime the total connection becomes 0 and then it reaches 10 and then again back to 0. I went through websites for this error where they mentioned error related DataSource object. Below is the details of the properties file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
   ss:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      hikari:
       connection-timeout: 5000
       maximum-pool-size: 10
       idle-timeout: 60000
       max-lifetime: 1800000
       minimum-idle: 2
       jdbc-url: ------URL---
```

Here is the configuration class function:

```
  @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.ss")
    public DataSource sourceDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    // EntityManager bean 
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sourceEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(sourceDataSource());
........... .
```

I tried solving this...but didn't got concrete solution. So how to remove this error ?

Comment: You have 2 datasources (according to your configuration) for one you don't set the max pool size, min pool size and idle time, so no idle checking is going to happen. \

Comment: same configuration is there for both the datasources.

Comment: Not according to what you posted.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, corrected that.

Comment: You should create a `DataSource` properties object to bind the properties which you then inject into the `sourceDatasource` method. Else those properties won't be bound to the datasource.

Comment: Do you know how to close the connection for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean containing the dataSource Object ?

Comment: If you have used nothing about the ordinary and don't mess around with connections yourself, things will close and return to the pool.